# Changing duration of video in VideoWriter Class

Tags: matlab, video

I want to record a 4 minute simulation of the frames that I am creating. Here is my code:

```
%% Creating the video with VideoWriter
writerObj = VideoWriter('RAW.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate=4;
open(writerObj);
k=0;
while k < N
   cell_prev=cell;
   cell=newStep_noise(cell_prev,n,H1,M,H2,D,K,P);
   diff_norm_vect=computeDiff(cell,n);
   scatter(X,Y,50,diff_norm_vect,'filled');
   frame = getframe;
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
   k=k+1;
end
close(writerObj);
```

I cannot use `writerObj.Duration=240;` as the duration is a read only property in the `VideoWriter` class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `duration` is `FrameRate*numberOfFrames`, you can reach the target duration by setting

```
writerObj.FrameRate = numberOfFrames/targetDurationInSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `writerObj.FrameRate` fixed at 4, then you can replace your your `while` loop with a simpler `for` loop:

```
...
writerObj.FrameRate = 4;
...
Duration = 240;
for k = 1:round(Duration/writerObj.FrameRate)
    ...
end
```

If `Duration` in not evenly divisible by the frame rate then the actual video duration may be longer or shorter by a frame. [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) or [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) could be used instead of [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) to guarantee that the the video is either always at least `Duration` seconds long or always less than or equal to `Duration` seconds, respectively.

By the way, `cell` is the name of a common data type in Matlab and thus probably not a good name for a variable.